# Want to invoke a base class using a generic with 'this' of child class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, base-class

So my problem is that I want to remove nulls for all my strings in complex objects like POCOs and DTOs.  I can do this but the method I am doing it seems like it could be better.  So I figured someone on Stack Overflow had a better way.

Base Class:

```
public class PropertyEmptySetter<T> where T : class
{
    T obj { get; set; }

    public PropertyEmptySetter(T myObj)
    {
        obj = myObj;
        UpdateStringProperties();
    }

    public PropertyEmptySetter()
    {
    }

    public void UpdateStringProperties()
    {
        foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList())
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType == (typeof(string)))
            {
                if(prop.GetValue(obj) == null)
                    prop.SetValue(obj, String.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Child Class (POCO Object):

```
public class POCO : PropertyEmptySetter<POCO>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Purpose { get; set; }

    public POCO()
    {
       var setter = new PropertyEmptySetter<POCO>(this);
    }
}
```

Testing it works:

```
private static string _s = "";

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var item = new POCO {Id = 1, Name = "Brett", Description = "Me"};

    var props = item.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        _s += "Type: " + prop.Name + "\tValue:" + (prop.GetValue(item) ?? "NULL") + Environment.NewLine;

    }

    Console.WriteLine(_s);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

So the above works but I was hoping to shorten it to something like the child constructor stating:

```
 public POCO() : base(this)
```

Ehh, ehhh.  Visual Studio does not like this and states "Cannot use 'this' in member initializer"

Or have the parameterless constructor in the base do something like

```
public PropertyEmptySetter()
{
    obj = (child)  // Yes I know this does not exist
        UpdateStringProperties();
}
```

I basically was hoping to scaffold up all the logic so that the inheritance just knows: "Oh you want this object you are creating RIGHT NOW, gotcha!"  It seems that I have to do this in the scope of the constructor and cannot get around that.  But I may just be ignorant of an easier way.  I do not want to this when instantiating the object outside of it, I want this so it just scaffolds up when the object is created inside itself and the base class.  Is this even possible or is the method I am showing the easiest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to make `PropertyEmptySetter` non-generic as it doesn't need to be. It just works on `this` and every class the inherits from it passes `this` simply by being `PropertyEmptySetter`:

```
public class PropertyEmptySetter
{
    public PropertyEmptySetter()
    {
        UpdateStringProperties();
    }

    public void UpdateStringProperties()
    {
        foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList())
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType == (typeof(string)))
            {
                if (prop.GetValue(obj) == null)
                    prop.SetValue(obj, String.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}

class POCO : PropertyEmptySetter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Purpose { get; set; }
}
```

If however, you still want to make it generic you can use a static builder method:

```
class Poco
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Purpose { get; set; }

    private Poco() {}

    public static Poco CreatePoco()
    {
        var poco = new Poco();
        new PropertyEmptySetter<POCO>(poco);
        return poco;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're missing key skills in **C#** and **.NET**.

Regarding your test application, first of all, it's always a terrible idea to concatenate strings in a loop. Strings are immutable in **.NET**, Everytime you concatenate strings, you're creating a new string. Use a `StringBuilder` instead

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var prop in item.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    sb.Append("Type: ");
    sb.Append(prop.Name);
    sb.Append("\tValue:");
    var value = prop.GetValue(item);
    if (value == null)
    {
        sb.Append(" NULL");
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append(" [");
        sb.Append(value);
        sb.Append("]");
    }
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Second, your implementation doesn't work and you haven't tested for what you're trying to avoid. If you try with this:

```
var item = new POCO {Id = 1, Name = "Brett", Description = null};
```

you'll get this:

```
Type: Id  Value: [1]
Type: Name  Value: [Brett]
Type: Description  Value: NULL
Type: Purpose  Value: []
```

You are deriving from a base classe only to criate a variable in the constructor that you throw away without doing anything usefull because all strings in the POCO class are all still initialized, thus null.

If you remove that from the `POCO` constructor:

```
public POCO()
{
}
```

and the `obj` from `PropertyEmptySetter<T>`:

```
public class PropertyEmptySetter<T> where T : class
{
    public PropertyEmptySetter()
    {
    }

    public void UpdateStringProperties()
    {
        foreach (var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType == (typeof(string)))
            {
                if(prop.GetValue(this) == null)
                    prop.SetValue(this, String.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var item = new POCO {Id = 1, Name = "Brett", Description = null};
item.UpdateStringProperties();
```

I think you'll get what you're looking for:

```
Type: Id  Value: [1]
Type: Name  Value: [Brett]
Type: Description  Value: []
Type: Purpose  Value: []
```

In OOP (Object Oriented Programming) the concept of hinheritance and parent-child is misleading. It's not like `POCO` is a child of `PropertyEmptySetter<T>` and `PropertyEmptySetter<T>` is a parent of `POCO`. `POCO` is also a `PropertyEmptySetter<T>` (more concretely, a `PropertyEmptySetter<POCO>`), but `PropertyEmptySetter<T>` is not necessarily a `POCO`.

If you don't want to tie your POCOs to `PropertyEmptySetter<T>` you can add a static method to `PropertyEmptySetter<T>`:

```
public class PropertyEmptySetter<T> where T : class
{
    public void UpdateStringProperties()
    {
        UpdateStringProperties(this as T);
    }

    public static T UpdateStringProperties(T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType == (typeof(string)))
            {
                if(prop.GetValue(obj) == null)
                    prop.SetValue(obj, String.Empty);
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }
}
```

and just have:

```
public class POCO : PropertyEmptySetter<POCO>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Purpose { get; set; }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var item = new POCO {Id = 1, Name = "Brett", Description = null};
PropertyEmptySetter<POCO>.UpdateStringProperties(item);
```

And beacuse the static method is returning the POCO, you can chain it:

```
var anotherItem = PropertyEmptySetter<POCO>.UpdateStringProperties(item);
```

And, by the way, you are not doing anything with it that can't be done on a `struct`, so you should remove the `class` constraint and just make it an extension class:

```
public static class PropertyEmptySetter
{
    public static T UpdateStringProperties<T>(this T obj) where T : class
    {
        foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType == (typeof(string)))
            {
                if(prop.GetValue(obj) == null)
                    prop.SetValue(obj, String.Empty);
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }
}
```

and use `UpdateStringProperties` like an instance method:

```
var item = new POCO {Id = 1, Name = "Brett", Description = null};
item = item.UpdateStringProperties();
```

The compiler will even infer the type in the invocation of `UpdateStringProperties`.

Comment: Your answer needs to be removed: 1. a 'string' is immutable but not in that it cannot be changed, you go off on a tangent on mutability which has nothing to do with question.  2. When I add to a collection from GetProperties of an object I return a collection of PropertyInfo based on the object it is invoking. If I add a breakpoint and see each property info it is easy to see this. You are stating something completely false off of assumption. 3. Your end answer has some merit but ignores the basic request to do this in construction NOT an outside class.

Comment: Would you care, for the enlignment of us all, to pinpoint and demonstrate what is "completely false"?

Comment: "Second, your implementation doesn't work and you haven't tested for what you're trying to avoid. If you try with this:"  You are assuming something I did not do.  But you are correct I could have worded it as 'I want to remove null instantiations' verus 'I want to remove nulls'.  Basically your entire response was assumption driven and insulting and insulting based on condititions you made up that were not in the example.  You could have said: "Explicit assignment will not account for this." and I would be fine.  Instead of you did what I said not to do and then assumed it was what I wanted.